Cannot import crystal report after configure HSTS
i try to import crystal report, but after i select the crystal report from local document, the screen show this element/xml. Does anyone facing this issue before? I found out this happen when i config HSTS in the tomcat web.xml. but this issue doesn’t happen at the other environment with same HSTS configured



